# Can't run node.js script on server reboot

Tags: debian, node.js, init.d

I need to listen events on port 3240 and I'm using node.js for that purpose. I need to execute my script with [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) tool. I also need to run `forever` on server reboot.

When I run `forever glh.js` everything works: `forever list` says there is a running process.

But when I'm trying to run forever on server reboot I can't get it working.

I've created a file in /etc/init.d with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

/var/www/yan/data/gitlabhook/runglh.sh &>/var/www/yan/data/gitlabhook/runglh.log
```

When I reboot the server, the output log is the following (the same as when I run it manually via console):

```
info:    Forever processing file: glh.js
```

But in this case forever doesn't start a process. `forever list` outputs:

```
info:    No forever processes running
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at last I figured out that the script runs on reboot and is working, it is just not outputed by `forever list`. Seems to be a forever's bug.